# why does this setup forming sub communicators deadlock in mpi4py

Tags: mpi, mpi4py

```
system: MacOSX 14.4.1
python: 3.11.8
mpi4py: 3.1.5
OpenMPI: 5.0.2 installed with homebrew
```

I have the following python script.  The deadlock happens when I have 3 MPI ranks.  I want to create a subcommunicator for ranks 0 and 1, and another for ranks 1 and 2.  This means that rank 1 only needs to know about the first sub communicator, rank 2 needs to know about the second, but rank 1 needs to know about both of them.

However, although rank 1 successfully creates the first communicator, it deadlocks when creating the second.  Why is that?

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
from typing import List

world_comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
world_size = world_comm.Get_size()
world_rank = world_comm.Get_rank()

assert world_size == 3

communicator_ranks = [
    [(0, 1)],
    [(0, 1), (1, 2)],
    [(1, 2)]
]

communicators: List[MPI.Comm] = []
for ranks in communicator_ranks[world_rank]:
    group = world_comm.group.Incl(ranks)
    print(f"rank: {world_rank}, forming communictor for ranks: {ranks}")
    comm = world_comm.Create(group)
    print(f"rank: {world_rank}, forming communictor for ranks: {ranks} -- DONE")
    communicators.append(comm)

world_comm.barrier()
print("all done")
```

when running `mpirun -n 3 python deadlock.py` I get the following printout:

```
> mpirun -n 3 python deadlock.py
rank: 2, forming communictor for ranks: (1, 2)
rank: 1, forming communictor for ranks: (0, 1)
rank: 0, forming communictor for ranks: (0, 1)
rank: 0, forming communictor for ranks: (0, 1) -- DONE
rank: 2, forming communictor for ranks: (1, 2) -- DONE
rank: 1, forming communictor for ranks: (0, 1) -- DONE
rank: 1, forming communictor for ranks: (1, 2)
```

Note, the last entry has no `DONE` counterpart and the program just sits there waiting forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is incorrect w.r.t. the MPI standard.

From MPI 4.2  chapter 7.4 page 325:

> If an MPI process calls with a nonempty group then all MPI processes
> in that group must call the function with the same group as argument,
> that is the same MPI processes in the same order. Otherwise, the call
> is erroneous.

You might try the `mpi4py` binding for `MPI_Comm_create_from_group()` instead, or use `MPI_GROUP_EMPTY`

Comment: Turns out there is another call: `world_comm.Create_group` succeeds

Comment: `MPI_Comm_create()` is a collective operation (e.g. all the ranks of the communicator must invoke it with compatible arguments) but `MPI_Comm_create_from_group()` is not, and that explains why the later works here.